# How Can I Animate Background Color Dynamically Added Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am adding some elements with ajax. For this example, i am adding user comments. When user make new comment, his comment viewing first place and (this is question) I want to add new background animation first comment div. But i know we cant animate color with Jquery. I can use JqueryUI highlight effect. But i cant select new added element. Off course use here delegate() or on().. But my all try failed.

I need help.

Some Code Example;

```
$("#DoCommentBtn").click(function(){
        var UserID      = 1,
            LookID      = 2,
            Comment     = $("#CommentInput").val(),
            CommentType = 0,
            PostData    = "USERID=" + UserID + "&LOOKID=" + LookID + "&Comment=" + encodeURI(Comment) + "&CommentType=" + CommentType;
            $("#CmAnm").fadeIn();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax.asp?cmd=docomment',
                dataType:'html',
                data:PostData,
                success:function(cevap) {
                    $("#CmAnm").fadeOut();
                    $("#CommentsArea").load("ajax.asp?cmd=LoadComments&LOOKID=" + LookID + "&PART=0");
                    //Now all comments loaded Here I must animate background first div in #CommentsArea Animation Example: Background color blue to white..  
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: could you draw your expected output ? and where you getting error

Comment: "But i know we cant animate color with Jquery". What makes you say this? Can you provide us with the desired result?

Comment: Actually, you CAN animate color with jQuery. Please make a fiddle.

Comment: I use some code with jsfiddle example;

<button type="button" id="animate">Animate</button>
<hr>
<div class="justDiv">
    JustDiv
</div>
<style>
.justDiv {
    background:#FF0000;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#animate").click(function(){
     $(".justDiv").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff",width:105 }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>

Just div expanding but not changing color..

Comment: Color not animating.. or am I doing wrong but code there is.. I try background , color and backgroundColor but fail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation Properties and Values

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality

(For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)

Docs : [JQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

So what can i do right now ?

I am adding this library;

Jquery.Color

And now jsfiddle example working.

Example Code :

```
$(".justDiv").animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff",width:105 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i know we cant animate color with Jquery

I'm not a jquery expert but i'm sure it is possible.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$( "#CommentsArea div:first-child" ).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 1000);
```

Should animate the background to white **#FFF** in 1 second *(1000ms)*

**Docs**: [jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - [jQuery UI .animate()](https://jqueryui.com/animate/)

EDIT:

changed **background** to **backgroundColor**

Comment: try using backgroundColor instead of background, just tested on console and worked

Comment: I comment up please read it. I can not animate with this code. But when i use this code : animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff", width:234}, 1000); just with animation working.. Color not change..